# Is there any option to calculate the pricing of certain resource in my GCP project.?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-billing

I need to calculate the pricing of selected resources like compute engine,dataproc and cloud sql in my gcp project. Is there any way to manage and calculate the cost programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Billing catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api) for this. You can get the price of the SKU, and then perform by yourselves the calculation that you want.

Comment: I want even to calculate the resource usage programatically. Ultimately I need the price as my result. Can I achieve this using the above method..?

Comment: Yes, but you have to implement these formulas by yourselves, and I'm not sure that will be easy, reliable, and stable in the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gcp pricing calculator for usage of resources in gcp [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

Comment: I think gcp price calculator is for estimating the cost, but I need to calculate the resource that is already consumed and the billing should be exact.

Comment: That you can go to billing option in the hamburger menu then select the cost breakdown , then choose the filter you want the costing for . Hope this helps